# How to manually prune and restart php-resque workers

Tags: php, resque, composer-php, php-resque

Very frequently php-Resque workers will be stuck on a job for days, and eventually all the workers gets stuck and the site stops working.The `php-resque` library was installed using Composer.

**Question:** I want to do the pruning manually. How do I access this function `pruneDeadWorkers()`? And if dead workers are found, how do I restart them?

[View Source](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque/blob/master/lib/Resque/Worker.php)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To prune the workers manually, include the vendor/chrisboulton/php-resque/lib/Resque/Worker.php file, instantiate a Worker, then call pruneDeadWorkers();

```
<?php 
include 'vendor/chrisboulton/php-resque/lib/Resque/Worker.php'; // If you're not already using composer autoloader

$worker = new Worker('default'); // the argument doesn't matter
$worker->pruneDeadWorkers();
```

php-resque is not shipped with a function to restart workers, take a look at [fresque](https://github.com/kamisama/Fresque) for that.

To avoid having dead workers, compile your php with `pcntl_fork`, to execute your jobs in a fork, and isolating them from the workers.

Answer (score 0):

first find worker list : 
`Resque_Worker::all();`
this contain workers id 
according to [php-resque doc](http://kamisama.me/2012/10/12/background-jobs-with-php-and-resque-part-4-managing-worker/)
type in command line

```
`kill workers id`
```